# Invalid HTTP_HOST header: '127.0.0.1:8000'. You may need to add '127.0.0.1' to ALLOWED_HOSTS. in Django

Tags: django

I'm getting this error whenever i'm trying to run my server locally.

Here is how i've configured the allowed hosts: But it doesn't seem to work...

```
 ALLOWED_HOSTS = env.list("ALLOWED_HOSTS", default=["*", '127.0.0.1:8000'])
```

Comment: where does it state that you should set port in allowed hosts

Comment: Try setting the allowed host without port number (i.e) '127.0.0.1'

Answer (score 1):

As [documented](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/settings/#allowed-hosts)

> Values in this list can be fully qualified names (e.g.
> 'www.example.com'), in which case they will be matched against the
> request’s Host header exactly (case-insensitive, **not including
> port**).

```
 ALLOWED_HOSTS = env.list("ALLOWED_HOSTS", default=["*", '127.0.0.1'])
```